# Meteor, Accounts.callLoginMethod() doesn't call custom login handler on mobile device

Tags: meteor

My code works as expected in desktop browser and on android emulator but it doesn't work on android device (debug mode via USB).

I've registered custom login handler in server code

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler("customLoginHandler", function (options) {
    console.log("customLoginHandler()");
});
```

Then on specific UI event I'm calling it from client code

```
console.log("calling custom login");

Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodArguments: [ {clientUser: "hello", clientPassword: "world"} ],
    userCallback: function() {
        console.log("clientCustomLogin callback");
    }
});

console.log("done");
```

Console output when running this code on desktop or android emulator

```
customLoginHandler()
```

on mobile

```
calling custom login
done
```

whole client code is located inside

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
```

block. Why the output is so different?

Meteor version 1.1.0.2, server OS - Linux, mobile - Android 4.4.2

Meteor is started by the command:

```
meteor run android-device
```

Packages installed:

```
$ meteor list
accounts-base    1.2.0  A user account system 
http             1.1.0  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
meteor-platform  1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
twbs:bootstrap   3.3.4  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: remove the app on android, then run `meteor run android-device`

**Long asnwer**.

I don't know why it is possible, but It looks like the app was not fully updated (or not updated at all starting from some point) on the mobile device.

I was playing with accounts-base, accounts-password and accounts-ui packages reinstallation, but then I noticed that when I replaced my template with standard {{> loginButtons}} (in main html file) nothing has changed on mobile after meteor rerunning and the application refreshing on android.

Then I just removed the app from android and started meteor again.

After that the applicated started to work as expected.